# How to find the last instance of a particular string in a file

Tags: windows

What is the easier way using command line tools, to find the last usage of a particular string in a file.

Comment: "What is the easier way..." easier way than what...?  What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is pretty vague, as you are asking for "the easier way" without giving a starting point (type of contents, for example).  Generally, I don't answer these since you do not show that you have done any research or trials and gotten stuck somewhere and imply that we are a script-writing service.

Anyway, in a case like this I'd turn to `Powershell`, since `cmd` is pretty pathetic, and use a command similar to:

```
select-string C:\Path\To\MyFile.txt -pattern "literalOrRegexPattern" | Select-Object -last 1
```

For example in a `.vimrc` with the contents:

```
set number
syntax on
set tabstop=4
set noexpandtab
```

Using the above to match a line beginning with `^set` (lines that start with "set") results in:

```
.vimrc:4:set noexpandtab
```

That's `filename:linenumber:text`.